# Rails pass predefined id to text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app I want to have already filed text_field_tag by `current_login.user.full_name`. Additionally I want to pass current_login.user.id inside this `text_field` as params[:physician_id]. What I did is pretty simple:

```
<%= text_field_tag "physician_id", current_login.user.id, class: 'form-control', value: current_login.user.full_name, disabled: true %>
```

With this code I've got:

```
pry> params['physician_id']
=> nil
```

If I add `<%= text_field_tag "physician_id", id: current_login.user.id (...)` I've got:

```
pry> params['physician_id']
=> {:id=>70, :class=>\"form-control\", :value=>\"Gary KZM JohnsonR\", :disabled=>true}
```

How to pass this `current_login.user.id` as a `params['physician_id']` inside text_field_tag? should I use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the method signature is

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

You cannot have both `current_login.user.id` and `value:` specified, they both map to `value` attribute of the `input`. Also your input is disabled so it is not being submitted with the form.

```rb
<%= text_field_tag "physician_id", current_login.user.id, class: "form-control", 
  value: current_login.user.full_name, disabled: true %>
```

Either you're looking for a select_field_tag or have separate `physician_name` input and a `physician_id` as hidden input

```rb
<%= text_field_tag "physician_name", current_login.user.full_name, class: "form-control" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "physician_id", current_login.user.id, class: "form-control" %>
```

This will submit as `params`

```
{"physician_id"=>"1", "physician_name"=>"name"}
```

However I suggest you don't do that, as this is not a secure way to deal with current_user attributes. I could submit any id as physician_id and probably get access to records that don't belong to me. You should assign these attributes inside of your controller instead.